# YAML Implicit keys need to be on a single line, Implicit map keys need to be followed by map values

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

```yaml
trigger:
- develop

pool:
  vmImage: windows-2019

- task: MSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '**/*.sln'
- task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    buildType: 'current'
    downloadType: 'single'
    itemPattern: '**/*.exe'
    downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
```

I get an error with this YAML in both Azure DevOps and using the YAML extension for VS Code.  I'm trying to build a Windows Service and then put the .exe file somewhere that I can download it.

Azure DevOps:
[image: azdo screenshot]
VSCode
[image: vscode screenshot]

Error:

> Implicit keys need to be on a single line, Implicit map keys need to
> be followed by map values

Comment: Can you please paste the full yaml? From the screenshot it looks like something is wrong with line 10, but line 8 is lit red too.

Comment: Added image of full YAML.  It's also in the question body.

Comment: thanks, maybe you could also try to use a code block for your code snippet. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Just a note, this error is generic, and in my case it was because of tab/spaces mixes (so nothing to do with the key) hope it helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although the error looks some what confusing, your are missing the keyword `steps`.

```yaml
trigger:
- develop

pool: 
  vmImage: windows-2019

steps:
- task: MSBuild@1 
  inputs: 
    solution: '**/*.sln'
- task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@1 
  inputs: 
    buildType: 'current' 
    downloadType: 'single' 
    itemPattern: '**/*.exe' 
    downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
```

Answer (score 3):

We've just run into the same error and it was being caused by invisible characters that appeared when we copied the code over from a Teams chat.
We've removed these "spaces" and replaced them with regular spaces and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

When I ran into this error, it was caused by the next line having an extra level of indentation.

Exact error text:

```
Nested mappings are not allowed in compact mappingsYAML
Implicit keys need to be on a single line
```

Incorrect

```
    MultiStockQtysResponse:
      type: array
      items:
        type: object
          required: [standardID, storeCode, qtyAvailable]
```

Correct

```
    MultiStockQtysResponse:
      type: array
      items:
        type: object
        required: [standardID, storeCode, qtyAvailable]
```

The error started on the line with `type: object`, but un-indenting `required...` fixed the error.