# Unexpected value in YAML

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

```
trigger:
  - develop

pool:
  vmImage: windows-2019

steps:
    - task: NuGetCommand@2
        inputs:
            command: "restore"
            restoreSolution: "**/*.sln"
            feedsToUse: "config"
    - task: MSBuild@1
        inputs:
            solution: "**/*.sln"
    - task: S3Upload@1
        inputs:
            regionName: "us-west-2"
            bucketName: "ssw-nonprod-ado-artifacts"
            globExpressions: "**"
            targetFolder: "nsspreproc"
```

I added the missing "steps" keyword as suggested on my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75261412/yaml-implicit-keys-need-to-be-on-a-single-line-implicit-map-keys-need-to-be-fol).

Now the errors I'm getting are:

/azure-pipelines.yml (Line: 11, Col: 12): Unexpected value

- /azure-pipelines.yml (Line: 12, Col: 5): Unexpected value
- /azure-pipelines.yml (Line: 13, Col: 5): Unexpected value
- /azure-pipelines.yml (Line: 14, Col: 5): Unexpected value
- /azure-pipelines.yml (Line: 16, Col: 12): Unexpected value
- /azure-pipelines.yml (Line: 17, Col: 5): Unexpected value
- /azure-pipelines.yml (Line: 19, Col: 12): Unexpected value
- /azure-pipelines.yml (Line: 20, Col: 5): Unexpected value
- /azure-pipelines.yml (Line: 21, Col: 5): Unexpected value
- /azure-pipelines.yml (Line: 22, Col: 5): Unexpected value

For example line 11 column 12 is right after the colon (:) on the first "inputs".

I've tried changing up the indentation and using single quotes vs double quotes, but none of that seems to help.  What am I missing?

Comment: YAML is whitespace-sensitive. Review the documentation and use a YAML linter to ensure you are formatting your YAML correctly. `inputs` and `task` should be at the same level of indentation. You have `inputs` indented further.

Comment: @DanielMann according to YAMLLint.com this is "Valid YAML!"

Comment: @Marcie No it isn't, and no it doesn't--I just checked. https://ibb.co/gJzcYGX

Comment: @DaveNewton here is what it shows for me:  https://ibb.co/sFJFhgw

Comment: @Marcie That's not the YAML shown in the question :shrug: I cut-and-pasted the YAML in the question. If you run a YAML linter on **different** YAML that there are different results isn't super-surprising.

Answer (score 1):

[Dave Newton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438992/dave-newton) is absolutely right, your YAML is **not** valid.

[image]

This is the valid version of your YAML:

```yaml
trigger:
  - develop
pool:
  vmImage: windows-2019
steps:
  - task: NuGetCommand@2
    inputs:
      command: restore
      restoreSolution: "**/*.sln"
      feedsToUse: config
  - task: MSBuild@1
    inputs:
      solution: "**/*.sln"
  - task: S3Upload@1
    inputs:
      regionName: us-west-2
      bucketName: ssw-nonprod-ado-artifacts
      globExpressions: "**"
      targetFolder: nsspreproc
```

[image]

Word of advice, please take a good look at your white spaces and indentation:

[image]